# Why does returning from _start segfault?

Tags: assembly, stack, system-calls, exit

I tried to put code not in the main function, but directly into `_start`:

```
    segment .text
    global _start
_start:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    ; ... program logic ...
    leave
    ret
```

Compile:

```
yasm -f elf64 main.s
ld -o main main.o
```

Run:

```
./main
Segmentation fault(core dumped)
```

I read, leave is

```
mov esp,ebp
pop ebp
```

But why is it that such an epilogue to the pop stack frame and the set base frame pointer to a previous frame's base results in a segmentation fault?

Indeed, making an exit system call exits gracefully.

Comment: `_start` is not called by the kernel, you cannot return from it.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more? I thought that it was ordinary routine.
How should one properly "return/exit" from it? Via exit system call? Write as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [ABI](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/article/402129/mpx-linux64-abi.pdf)<sup>1</sup> the stack at the entry on `_start` is

[image: Stack at entry on _start]

There is no "return address".
The only way to exit a process is through `SYS_EXIT`

```
xorl %edi, %edi   ;Error code
movl $60, %eax    ;SYS_EXIT
syscall
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Section *3.4.1 Initial Stack and Register State*.

Comment: That answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

The `LEAVE` instruction is defined to not cause any exceptions, so it cannot be the source of your fault. You should be using GDB. Debuggers are invaluable in solving these sorts of problems.

This is what happens:

> $ gdb ./main
>   [...]
>   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
>   
>   (gdb) x /gx $rsp-8
>   0x7fffffffe650: 0x0000000000000001

So, most likely your program ran to completion, but the first thing on the stack that 0x0000000000000001. `RET` popped that into the `RIP` register, and then it segfaulted because that address is not mapped.

I don't write a lot of code on Linux, but I would bet that `_start` is required to use the exit system call. The only way you could possibly return to a useful address is if the kernel put a function somewhere that would do this for you.

Comment: Yes, before asking question I used gdb and show 
`6 leave
(gdb) n
_start() at main.s:7
7 ret
(gdb) n
0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()`
Did not post because do not know what "??" means.

Comment: I also think about setting rip to unmapped location in memory, however, it would be nice to know accurately.

Comment: It means that the address is not in a valid module. Since GDB doesn't know what module it belongs to, it prints "??". The key thing to notice here is that 0x0000000000000001 is not a valid, executable address. When RIP points to an invalid or non-executable address, it is usually caused by either a RET to a bad address or an indirect JMP or CALL to a bad address. If a RET, as is the case here, the 8 bytes below the top of stack will match RIP. If a JMP or CALL, sometimes a register will match RIP.

Comment: Indeed you'd expect the first thing on the stack would be the value 1 as this is where Linux passes the `argc` value and a program invoked without any arguments has an `argc` of 1.

Comment: Useful tip about arguments. So to get argc and argv one should use ebp + 8 and ebp + 16 stack offsets respectively?